# Populate drop-down form the database and insert that value into another in the same database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am populating data into the dropdown from the Assembly table(the values in the table was added by the user itself using php). Now I want to Assembly_Name in the Part Table. Want to select the value from this drop-down menu and need to insert into the Assembly_Name column of the Part table. I am not able to select the dropdown value and insert it into the Part table.

Part.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert_part.php" method="post">
<!--Assembly_Id: <input type="text" name="Assembly_Id">-->
<?PHP 
// Connect to your database ** EDIT THIS **
mysql_connect("localhost","root","abc"); // (host, username, password)

// Specify database ** EDIT THIS **
mysql_select_db("test") or die("Unable to select database"); //select db

$result = mysql_query("select assembly_id,assembly_name from assembly ORDER BY  Assembly_Id"); 

echo '<select name="assembly_name"><OPTION>'; 
echo "Select an option</OPTION>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$assembly_name= $row["assembly_name"]; 
echo "<OPTION value=\"$assembly_name\">$assembly_name</OPTION>"; 
} 
echo '</SELECT>';
?>


Part_name: <input type="text" name="Part_name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<hr><hr>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Part ORDER BY Part_Id");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Assembly Name</th>
<th>Part Id</th>
<th>Part Name</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Assembly_Name'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Part_Id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Part_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

insert_part.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$assembly_name = isset($_POST['assembly_name'])
$sql="INSERT INTO Part (assembly_name,Part_Id, Part_Name) VALUES ('$_POST[assembly_name]','$_POST[Part_Id]','$_POST[Part_name]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
header("Location:part.php");
exit;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

While Submitting the Value, I am getting the below Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   C:\wamp\www\insert_part.php on line 10

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Try to understand what your error is trying to tell you. There is a variable issue on line 10.

Step 2: Check the code for why there could possibly be an issue with a variable in use.

Following this, checking the lines above you will find that the statement on line 9 was not completed with a `;` and ran into an "unexpected" variable when reaching line 10

You also do not appear to be submitting a `$_POST['Part_Id']`

Also, you want quotes in you `$_POST` such as `$_POST['assembly_name']` in your SQL statment.

Comment: you're right, although those only cause notices and should work in theory. Just bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Line 9 you're missing a semicolon:

```
$assembly_name = isset($_POST['assembly_name']);
```

But as @Lion says, do change to using prepared statements. As it is this code is very insecure :(